# openzeppelin ReentrancyGuard Constructor

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, tokens, openzeppelin, reentrant-attacks

I am trying to use the openzeppelin ReentrancyGuard contract within my ERC721 Token smart contract. Since this ReentrancyGuard contract has a constructor, I am required to declare it in my contract. However, since I am already declaring the constructor for my ERC721 Token, I am receiving an error, stating "More than one constructor defined". How can I solve this issue?

```
 contract MyContract is ERC721, ReentrancyGuard {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "TOK") public {
    }
    constructor () ReentrancyGuard() internal {
    }
 }
```

Thank you. J

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add it to the original constructor:

```
contract MyContract is ERC721, ReentrancyGuard {
    constructor() ERC721("MyToken", "TOK") ReentrancyGuard() public {
    }
 }
```

With that said, I do not believe OpenZeppelin's ReentrancyGuard has a constructor. You may want to verify that.

Comment: Actually Shane, I had another question if I may. In theory MyContract should be public, while the ReentrancyGuard one should be Internal. If I declare them both as you suggested, both will be public. Not sure if this could be an issue. (Forgot to mention that ReentrancyGuard does have a constructor.)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the ReentrancyGuard code?

Comment: Actually, although there is a constructor, one does not need to call it. Thanks again.